# Weird crash using std::minmax_element - vector iterator not dereferencable

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, iterator, dereference

My app crashes at moment when it shouldn't. What's more - yesterday it was crashing only in exe compiled in Debug mode or when running under debugger. The Release version was running well. Now it's also crashing in Release but nothing has changed in the code. I'm compiling with MSVC. When I was working with GCC as I remember it wasn't crashing (same code), however I didn't compile to Debug.

The code:

```
   std::vector<float> xVec, yVec, zVec;


   for(auto& mesh : m_meshes)
   {
      std::pair<float, float> minMaxX, minMaxY, minMaxZ;
      std::tie(minMaxX, minMaxY, minMaxZ) = mesh.getMinMaxCoords();

      xVec.push_back(minMaxX.first);
      xVec.push_back(minMaxX.second);

      yVec.push_back(minMaxY.first);
      yVec.push_back(minMaxY.second);

      zVec.push_back(minMaxZ.first);
      zVec.push_back(minMaxZ.second);
   }

   auto x = std::minmax_element(xVec.begin(), xVec.end());
   auto y = std::minmax_element(yVec.begin(), yVec.end());
   auto z = std::minmax_element(zVec.begin(), zVec.end());

   m_size = {
               *x.second - *x.first,
               *y.second - *y.first,
               *z.second - *z.first
            };
```

To make the code clear:

1. It is body of a method calculating size (a min cuboid in which we can fit the model) of a model.
2. `Mesh::getMinMaxCoords` finds the furthest vertices on x, y and z axes (both directions) and returns an adequate `std::tuple`. (I hope you get what I mean but it's not that important)
3. `m_size` is glm::vec3. Just a simple wrapper for 3 floats.

Just to make the code clear for you, but it's nothing to do with the problem (i think so).

std::minmax_element is searching in range [first, last) so it doesn't touch .end() iterator. Vectors (i mean conteners - `xVec`, `yVec` and `zVec`) still exist while dereferencing so I don't get what can be wrong. To be sure I tried to call minmax_element on range .begin() ; (.end() - 1) just in case microsoft made a mistake in implementation and the function was searching in [first, last] but nothing has changed.

Any ideas what can be causing the crash?

Comment: Check to make sure the vectors are not empty before you call `minmax_element`.  If they are then you need to look at your fill vector code.

Comment: Well... Looks like it's problem with assimp (i use to load models) because m_meshes (it's std::vector) is empty (and so the xVec, yVec and zVec are also empty). But it's weird because it was working... Huh, maybe i will compile assimp one more time.